# Load image different size

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I have an image in my supporting files folder that I want to use the whole width of the cellphone. They are like this:

```
img.png -> 320x205
img@2x.png -> 750x410
img@3x.png -> 1242x615
```

I load the image like this:

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"img"];
```

When I log the size of this image I get:

```
NSLog(@"@@@ Width: %f - Height: %f", img.size.width, img.size.height);
@@@ Width: 375.000000 - Height: 205.000000
```

Why my image loads with different size from its file?

Comment: well thechnically your image shows the rght value. If img @2x is of size 750x410, then img shud be 375x205 which is right.

Comment: so I may be getting this image size wrong. I want my image to be the whole iphone width. In iphone 5 I have 320dp and the scale is 1, right? So it should be 320px of width. And in iphone 6 I have 375dp and the scale is 2, so 750px of width. Am I thinking wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`size.width` or `size.height` are measured in **point**, not **pixel**.

Apple uses points that allows images to be scaled independently of the resolution of the phone.

Images are then rendered at different scale for different phone.

@1x: original iPhones

@2x: iPhone 4, 5, 6

@3x: iPhone 6 plus

You can get the scale value by:

```
CGFloat scale = [UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
```

Answer (score -1):

Here 2x and 3x means the size of image will be 2 in to original image and 3 in original image.
You don't have the image size in that format so it will show you this type of output.

> Example:- If my image 1x is :- 320 * 240 Than 2x will be :- 640 * 480
>   And 3x will be:- 960 * 720
>   This is proper format to put 2x and 3x images. After doing thia your log will show correct answer